# How to Add Expires Headers?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm using YSlow in Safari to try and improve my website speed, and it reported:

> Grade F on Add Expires headers There are 9 static components without a far-future expiration date.
>   (2014/5/29) http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trade+Winds
>   (2012/4/15) http://mydomain.com/example.css

What's the best practice to Add Expires Headers in html?
My host is GoDaddy, and the .htaccess file they provide is blank.

This is what I've tried so far ...

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
 ExpiresDefault      "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests 
# in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
 ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
 ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
 ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
 ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
 ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"

 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. The solution not only depends on your host (GoDaddy in my case), but the type of account you have (Linux Classic, in my case) as well.

My solution was to create a .htaccess file in the root directory of my ftp (plaintext) and paste the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Activate mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive on

# locally cache common image types for 7 days
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"

# cache CSS files for 24 hours
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
```